# Injecting an html element into index.html angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular2-services

i am developing a website in angular and i am in a situation where i have to inject a html element into index.html from a service. ie i have a service called InjectorService and which is provided in the app.component as

```
constructor(private injectorService :InjectorService) {
    this.injectorService.init();
}
```

When the init method is executed, i want to inject

```
<iframe src="./url.html" id="iframe" width="0"
    height="0" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Into my body tag of index.html , as a result which should look like

```
<body>
     <iframe src="./url.html" id="iframe" width="0"
        height="0" style="display:none"></iframe>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Is there any way this could be achieved ? Please help

Comment: The term 'injecting' is misleading. See Renderer and Renderer2 providers.

Comment: @estus i don't think he can use Renderer as he wants to add html outside angular app.

Comment: @Dhyey Why is that? Renderer provides an abstraction for entire DOM, not just app root element.

Comment: renderer2 worked for me :) Thank you :)